# Chat rooms : need header with standard links back to sites

Tags: feature-request, chat, top-bar

Chat rooms do not seem to have the standard header menu at the top of the page, making returning and transferring to a site somewhat tedious.

You don't always want to go back to the site you came from - I know many users are involved in multiple sites - so browser back buttons are not always ideal and the only choices at the moment at a link to the "parent" site of the chat room or a link to the available chat rooms for that site.

**So could the standard site header menu be added to chat rooms?**

Note that I know about the footer linking back to the site associated with a particular chat, but I think that either the footer should include the standard header links or be replaced by the header (which would be more consistent anyway).

Comment: The fact that we're apparently left to rely on non-generic third party solutions and that this has been requested before (and there are related requests, it seems) with no action, despite an "improvement" to the top header does not bode well.  Well done to @Shadow-Wizard for finding the duplicate - I didn't see one myself when I searched.

Comment: The reason that things like the script recommended in an answer even exist  is because it's impossible for SE to make everyone happy. I don't *personally* feel the need for a top bar in chat. If there were one I'd probably not complain about it but I don't see a need, either. The API and all of our wonderful users do a great job of making scripts that help users get the SE experience they want without the staff devs having to make the site absurdly configurable. The team only has so much time and there are a ton of requests for improvements with various levels of support.

Answer (score 2):

#### So could the standard site header menu be added to chat rooms?

While you are waiting for the normal 6-8 *time periods* to pass before your feature request is implemented you might want to consider installing the wonderful [Top Bar for Chat Rooms](https://stackapps.com/questions/7404/top-bar-for-chat-rooms) script:

> Provides a fully functional top bar, including realtime notifications, easy chat server switching, and fast room list searching, at the top of all chat rooms. Keep tabs on your inbox and site activity while chatting.
>
> [image]
>
> Features:
>
> - Fully functional with dropdowns and realtime notifications.
> - Topbar background can match chat room theme.
> - Adds a dropdown that lets you search for rooms directly (with optional search-as-you-type support and the ability to open rooms in
>   the same tab or a new one).
> - Adds chat server links to SE dropdown (click server name to open in new window, click "switch" to open in same window), with optional
>   auto-rejoin favorite rooms. Makes using multiple chat servers
>   convenient: